# Find the difference between all the values in the array and check whether difference in present in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I want to write a program which would calculate the difference between all the values of an array and find whether the difference is also present in the array or not.

For eg,

```
a = [1,2,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    j = i+1
    for j in range(len(a)):
        dif = a[i] - a[j]
        if dif in a:
            print a[i], a[j], dif
```

The output here would be,

```
2 1 1
4 2 2
5 1 4
5 4 1
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this? I don't want to use any python in built functions here. Without that is it possible to improve the algorithm?

Any help would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: `range` and `len` are what I would call "built-in" functions, along with print. So, you're making arbitrary constraints.

Comment: Also the code does not give you the output you provided. And `j = i + 1` does not do anything as you "overwrite" `j` with a different value in the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#cobinations) to achieve this:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [1,2,4,5]

for i, j in combinations(a, 2):
    dif = j - i  # OR, dif = abs(j - i) for checking against absolute value
    if dif in a:
        print j, i, dif
```

Above code will print:

```
2 1 1
5 1 4
4 2 2
5 4 1
```